# What regular expression does jQuery use for their email validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Jquery can validate email addresses:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

What regular expression (if any) does jQuery use for their email validation?
I'd like to do something similar, except using javascript regex.

Thanks!

### update:

**Why do I ask?**
I'm using it for the pattern attribute of my `<input>` elements.

I ended up using this:

```
^\S+@(([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/NQPhs/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It uses this regex borrowed from [Scott Gonzalez](http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/lib/email.js)...

```
/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i
```

[Source](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L1037).

There is no difference between a regex used in a jQuery plugin than a *normal* JavaScript regex.

Comment: Thanks! Does this seam practical for inline form validation?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean! :)

Comment: @Web_Designer: Well, it's long because it validates against the RFC spec. This will guarantee the format is correct, but won't guarantee the email exists. Send an email there if you need to confirm that.

Comment: @Web_Designer - Too many sites reject my *real* - *actual* email address that is *perfectly valid* (it does work after all) because they use too simple of a regex.

Comment: @Web_Designer - If you want something short then how about a really permissive pattern to see if the input is at least in the ballpark. Or in the ballpark's carpark: `/^[^\s].*@[^\s]+\.[^\s]+$/` - why obsess about it beyond that? Better to accept some invalid addresses than to reject valid ones because you got the regex slightly wrong, and in the end the person typing the address is responsible for what they type.

Comment: @StephenP I made a edit to my question with the `regex` i'm using. Try your email address in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/NQPhs

Comment: @Web_Designer pretty cool, it does work in the fiddle with my addresses. It did reject some things I know are legal - however uncommon they are - because, in essence, almost anything you can think of is legal to the left of the `@` as long as it's correctly quoted/escaped. I don't even bother validating the field because I have to send a confirmation email *anyway*.