# Devise `find_first_by_auth_conditions` explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I am having a tough time understanding this code from [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), even though I've read the documentation and done some research.

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  signin = conditions.delete(:signin)
  where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) =
    :value", {:value => signin.downcase }]).first
end
```

Please explain the components of this portion of the above method:

```
where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) =
  :value", {:value => signin.downcase }]).first
```

Comment: The first result of the query running against the warden conditions plus the username or email equals the signin value. What's the issue?

Comment: @DaveNewton: Thanks, can you break it down in a simpler form. I am not able to understand it as a whole.

Comment: `warden_conditions.dup` - duplicate the warden conditions.  Then `conditions.delete(:signin)` delete the sign in value.  Then find the first record with those conditions and the username or email is the signin value as Dave says

Comment: Maybe you are confused by the fact that `conditions.delete(:signin)` returns the deleted value?

Comment: Can anyone write the equivalent query for the same. where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) =
            :value", { :value => signin.downcase }]).first

Comment: `where(conditions)` depends by `warden_conditions` contents; the rest is translated, when `signin` is f.e. `Alfred`, to `lower(username) = 'alfred' OR lower(email) = 'alfred'`

Comment: That *is* the query for it. Obviously you understand the username and email part, right? We don't *know* what the warden conditions are. "first" is the first one. There's nothing else left in the query. Plus your log will *show* the emitted SQL.

Comment: Also, please don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I am sorry, i come from JS and PHP background and feel very hard to digest some part of code. We don't write code like this instead perform queries.

Comment: @theJava These *are* queries; it's an almost-direct translation to SQL. The only real difference is that you can "build up" queries using multiple `where` clauses. `first` does a `limit 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# arg is Hash, so assign to variable and downcase
x = warden_conditions[:signin].downcase

# create duplicate to preserve orig
c = warden_conditions.dup

# delete `:signin`
c.delete(:signin)

# if email, only search for email
if x =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
  y = self.where(c).where(:email => x) # self is implied, but optional--so we use it here for clarity 

# if not email, only search for name
else
  y = self.where(c).where(:username => x)
end

# y is array, so should be only one AR obj or empty array considering they are unique
# `Array#first` will return `nil` or AR obj
return y.first
```

regex via:
[validate email with regex jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572254/validate-email-with-regex-jquery)

The above code considers all previous records for columns `email` and `username` to be stored as lowercase as follows:

```
before_save :downcase_fields

def downcase_fields
  self.email.downcase
  self.username.downcase
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this whole code, but again what your code has to do with this.. where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) =
                :value", { :value => signin.downcase }]).first

Comment: Can u write the equivalent query for it.

Comment: @theJava Basically it's not equivalent, but close enough for illustrative purposes. Hope it helps. `lower(username)` queries column as if it was all lowercase with `signin.downcase` so devise doesn't need to know if any records were stored with uppercase or lowercase chars.

Comment: where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) =
                :value", { :value => signin.downcase }]).first Does this part of code perform check on where(condition)

Comment: @theJava the regexp is to explain the "long way" with two queries that the devise query turns into one using `OR`

Comment: @theJava No, `where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => signin.downcase }])` is only performed on the records that remain after this separate query `where(conditions)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50628/discussion-between-thejava-and-awesome)