# Email validation with jQuery, noobish problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, email-validation

I am trying to make e-mail validation in jQuery, but it really doesn't work in the way I want. Please share your knowledge with me, thank you in advance !

So first if should check if there is more than 1 @ -> if is "invalid", if it is not 'else if' check if there is at least 1 '@' and '.' , if this is wrong 'else' it is invalid. But it doesn't work :(

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').focusout(function(){
      if($(this).val().indexOf('@') > 0){
        $('.output').html('Invalid E-mail')
      }else if($(this).val().indexOf('@') > -1 &&
       $(this).val().indexOf('.') > -1){
        $('.output').html('Valid E-mail');
      }else{
          $('.output').html('Invalid E-mail')
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<input name='input' placeholder='Your E-mail'/></br></br>
          <p class='output'></p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [validate email with regex jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572254/validate-email-with-regex-jquery)

Comment: Please give examples of what kinds of addresses work and don't work. I notice that the first `if` probably should be `==0`, perhaps? Or are you misunderstanding what `indexOf()` does?

Comment: Where is your HTML ? Please add that as well.

Comment: @KenY-N Perhaps => `>= 0`

Comment: @KenY-N Dear Friend for example after passing 'abcdef@www.com' - outcome is "invalid" the same with any other combination, or maybe I misunderstand 'indexOf()' ;

Comment: @AlwaysHelping My dear friend ! I added HTML which is used by quoted code, thank you for your time !